# Delete duplicated rows MySQL

Tags: mysql

We want to delete duplicated rows on our MySQL database, and we have tried  a lot of queries, but for unfortunately we haven't succeeded yet. We found this query on several posts, but didn't work either:

```
DELETE t1 FROM Raw_Validated_backup AS t1 INNER JOIN Raw_Validated_backup AS t2 
    ON t1.time_start=t2.time_start 
    AND t1.time_end=t2.time_end 
    AND t1.first_temp_lpn=t2.first_temp_lpn 
    AND t1.first_WL=t2.first_WL 
    AND t1.first_temp_lpn_validated=t2.first_temp_lpn_validated 
    AND t1.second_temp_lpn=t2.second_temp_lpn 
    AND t1.second_WL=t2.second_WL 
    AND t1.second_temp_lpn_validated=t2.second_temp_lpn_validated 
    AND t1.third_temp_lpn=t2.third_temp_lpn 
    AND t1.third_WL=t2.third_WL 
    AND t1.third_temp_lpn_validated=t2.third_temp_lpn_validated 
    AND t1.first_temp_rising=t2.first_temp_rising 
    AND t1.first_WR=t2.first_WR 
    AND t1.first_temp_rising_validated=t2.first_temp_rising_validated 
    AND t1.second_temp_rising=t2.second_temp_rising 
    AND t1.second_WR=t2.second_WR 
    AND t1.second_temp_rising_validated=t2.second_temp_rising_validated 
    AND t1.third_temp_rising=t2.third_temp_rising 
    AND t1.third_WR=t2.third_WR 
    AND t1.third_temp_rising_validated=t2.third_temp_rising_validated 
    AND t1.id<t2.id;
```

Message we receive after running query: `No errors, 0 rows affected, taking 40,4 s`

Comment: Incidentally, if operationally possible, it's often far quicker to create a new table, retaining just the rows you want to keep, and then dropping/archiving the old table and renaming the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
select max(id) id
from Raw_Validated_backup
group by <list of all the columns except id>
```

returns all the ids for the rows that you want to keep.
So delete the rest:

```
delete from Raw_Validated_backup
where id not in (
  select t.id from (
    select max(id) id
    from Raw_Validated_backup
    group by <list of all the columns except id>
  ) t
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4FaFc2QY7W7bL9bQGEk6Vo/0).
Another option with a self join:

```
delete v1 
from Raw_Validated_backup v1 inner join Raw_Validated_backup v2
on v1.time_start = v2.time_start and v1.time_end = v2.time_end and .......
and v1.id < v2.id;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4FaFc2QY7W7bL9bQGEk6Vo/2).

Comment: Use `USING (fieldslist)` instead of `ON` - it is shorter and more clear.

Comment: Just tested and worked as wished. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Akina I agree `using` should be handy in this case but then the last condition `v1.id < v2.id` should be moved to a WHERE clause.

Comment: *the last condition `v1.id < v2.id` should be moved to a WHERE clause* Of course.